# Webpack Error when trying to run reactJS app (w. typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, package.json

I'm trying to get webpack to work in my ReactJS & typescript app but I'm getting this error, and I can't figure out what I am missing. I've got a webpack.config.js file, shown further down and I have tsconfig.json and my scripts from package.json, seen further down:

**Error Message**

```
    C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project\react-crud>yarn start
yarn run v1.19.1
$ webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot
(node:15192) Warning: require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project\react-crud\webpack.config.js from C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project\react-crud\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename webpack.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project_inspired\react-crud\package.json.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project_inspired\react-crud\webpack.config.js
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project_inspired\react-crud\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project_inspired\react-crud\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project_inspired\react-crud\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\perni\Projects\typescript_project_inspired\react-crud\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is how my webpack config file looks, can provide more code if needed. 
**webpack.config.js**

```
    const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
// webpack will take the files from ./src/index
    entry: './src/index',
// and output it into /dist as bundle.js
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
// adding .ts and .tsx to resolve.extensions will help babel look for .ts and .tsx files to transpile
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
// we use babel-loader to load our jsx and tsx files
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            },
// css-loader to bundle all the css files into one file and style-loader to add all the styles  inside the style tag of the document
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'] // ?name=[name].[ext] is only necessary to preserve the original file name
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        })


    ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start:build": "tsc -w",
    "start:run": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently npm:start:*",
    "bundle": "webpack"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

What Node version you are using? I resolved the same error by changing node version to `12.10.0`

depending upon your OS install NVM and then

```
nvm install 12.10.0
nvm use 12.10.0
```

then restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR: Remove the `"type": "module"` from the package.json file. That should solve the problem.

If `type` field is set to `module` then, it expects every `.js` file in your directory to be of **ESModule** type instead of CommonJS. It also means `webpack.config.js` and other webpack helper files like loaders which are loaded dynamically by Webpack using CommonJS/Node.js `require()` must be of **ESModule** as well.

Removing this field from the `package.json` should not impact as long as you are building for an application.

#### Authoring for libraries

If you are building/authorizing a library for NPM distribution, then it is a different story. If you intend to publish entire library as set of **ESModules**, then removal is not an option for you.

To solve library issue, you can use alternative approach of renaming Webpack config file to `webpack.config.cjs`. The `.cjs` extension tells Node that it is a CommonJS module even if package.json has `"type": "module` set.

Comment: When I rename to `cjs`, I get this: `A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory`